# What kind of airplane is this that has blue cheatlines and a protruding side cover?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Consider:

[image]

Which airplane is this? I suspect it is Russian, but it's too poor quality for me to tell. I'm pretty sure it is military.

Comment: Did you take the photo yourself? Can you describe it a bit more? If it's from an online source, where did you find it? [Let us know](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/55012/edit), thanks.

Comment: got challenged by a friend so its pretty vauge, I suspect the white bulb is some sort of signal intelligence thing or a radar of some sorts, the blue lines are pretty common on russian military aircrafts for example the an-72 wich makes me think it is russian.

Comment: After looking at the accepted answer, I look again at the blurry OP photo and see Ил-18, but I never would have been able to read it if I hadn't known what to look for!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a puzzle, not a question about aviation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm not sure why the reason for asking a question matters, if the question itself is on-topic? The OP is asking for aircraft identification based on limited information, and that's definitely on-topic here.

Comment: @Pondlife Because it serves no purpose other than "[just mindless social fun](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)", something that should be avoided because they have no lasting value and does not even help OP.

Comment: @Pondlife The question is just a game. The only reason the question exists is because somebody _who knew the answer_ deliberately obscured that answer and requested that it be found again. One could create an infinite number of such questions, none of which serve any purpose other than being questions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Below is the full photo, it's an Ilyushin Il-22PP Porubshchik electronic warfare plane.

[image]

> The Il-22PP Porubschik was designed in late 2000s on the basis of the Soviet [Il-18 passenger aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-18) made in mid 1970s. According to media reports, the aircraft is capable to disable most modern electronic warfare systems installed on foreign planes, air defense systems, as well as unmanned aerial vehicles.

Image and article: https://www.ruaviation.com/news/2017/3/31/8382/